# Android MediaPlayer does not display video, only play audio

Tags: android, video, media-player, emulation, surfaceview

I have a video file in location /sdcard/abc/a.3gp. Now when I try to play the file in android emulator using the media player that I have just created, I get only the audio, the video is not displayed. The screen remains blank (when it is supposed to play the video).

Here is the media player code that I am using:

```
package com.example.helloandroid;
import com.example.helloandroid.R;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class HelloAndroidActivity extends Activity implements
OnBufferingUpdateListener, OnCompletionListener,
OnPreparedListener, OnVideoSizeChangedListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private static final String TAG = "MediaPlayerDemo";

private int mVideoWidth;

private int mVideoHeight;

private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

private SurfaceView mPreview;

private SurfaceHolder holder;

private String path;

private Bundle extras;

private static final String MEDIA = "media";

private static final int LOCAL_AUDIO = 1;

private static final int STREAM_AUDIO = 2;

private static final int RESOURCES_AUDIO = 3;

private static final int LOCAL_VIDEO = 4;

private static final int STREAM_VIDEO = 5;

private boolean mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;

private boolean mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;


/**
 * 
 * Called when the activity is first created.
 */
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mPreview = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    holder = mPreview.getHolder();

    holder.addCallback(this);

    holder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    extras = getIntent().getExtras();


}

private void playVideo() {

    doCleanUp();
    try {

             path = "/sdcard/abc/a.3gp";
             if (path == "") {

                    // Tell the user to provide a media file URL.
                    Toast

                            .makeText(

                                    HelloAndroidActivity.this,

                                    "Please edit MediaPlayerDemo_Video Activity, "
                                            + "and set the path variable to your media file path."

                                            + " Your media file must be stored on sdcard.",

                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }                                   


        // Create a new media player and set the listeners

        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);

        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);

        mMediaPlayer.prepare();

        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(this);

        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    }

     catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);

    }
}


public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer arg0, int percent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onBufferingUpdate percent:" + percent);


}

public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onCompletion called");

}

public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {

    Log.v(TAG, "onVideoSizeChanged called");

    if (width == 0 || height == 0) {

        Log.e(TAG, "invalid video width(" + width + ") or height(" + height + ")");

        return;
    }

    mIsVideoSizeKnown = true;

    mVideoWidth = width;

    mVideoHeight = height;

    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {

        startVideoPlayback();
    }

}

public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaplayer) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onPrepared called");

    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = true;

    if (mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed && mIsVideoSizeKnown) {

        startVideoPlayback();
    }

}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder, int i, int j, int k) {

    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceChanged called");


}

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceholder) {

    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceDestroyed called");

}


public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    Log.d(TAG, "surfaceCreated called");

    playVideo();



}

@Override

protected void onPause() {

    super.onPause();

    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();

}

@Override

protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

    releaseMediaPlayer();
    doCleanUp();

}

private void releaseMediaPlayer() {

    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {

        mMediaPlayer.release();

        mMediaPlayer = null;

    }
}


private void doCleanUp() {

    mVideoWidth = 0;

    mVideoHeight = 0;

    mIsVideoReadyToBePlayed = false;

    mIsVideoSizeKnown = false;

}

private void startVideoPlayback() {

    Log.v(TAG, "startVideoPlayback");

    holder.setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);

    mMediaPlayer.start();

   }
  }
```

....................................................................

Layout->main.xml file is:

```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:id="@+id/home_container"  
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <VideoView 
       android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

       </FrameLayout>
```

............................................................................

I am not sure if the error is in the xml file or in the code.

Moreover in the logs there is no trace of the error.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it seems like the one of wide-known Android emulator's disadvantages. It has very limited support of media playing, so video in most cases can't perform well. Even Google engineers advices to use real device and not an emulator to test MediaPlayer-related issues.

Answer (score 0):

use SurfaceView  in .xml file instead of VideoView

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
  android:id="@+id/home_container"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent">

   <SurfaceView 
   android:id="@+id/surface_view" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />

   </FrameLayout>
```

Let us know once you resolved problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use videoview, it's a wrapper of mediaplayer, easy to settup.
P/s: i saw in your code `mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(holder);` it's nonsense, you should use `mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(surfaceHolder);` inside `surfaceCreated` or pass surfaceHolder as a param in `playvideo()`